# insert com where onde não tenho o valor completo

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Exemplo, eu já tenho na tabela o seguinte valor na coluna NUM_IMPRESSAO:

> K3244.K1019706.FSJC.08915

O novo valor que quero inserir tem apenas os 4 últimos digitos (08915) e preciso inseri-lo na mesma linha. Segue o select que tentei fazer:

```
def update_table(file_name, id):
        date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time())).strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))

        c.execute(f'UPDATE IMPRESSAO SET BINARY = ?,  DATA_ENVIO_BINARY = ? WHERE NUM_IMPRESSAO LIKE ?;', (file_name, date, id))
        c.commit()
        select_all()
```

Porém não está dando certo.

Answer (score 0):

Estou supondo que o id seja o NUM_IMPRESSAO, 
o que você precisa fazer é um `split` e colocar o "." como valor para dividir a `string` em um `array`.

```
novoValor = str(id).split('.')

novoValor = novoValor[-1]
```

ou utilizar outro método da classe `string` que é o `rfind` que  retorna o valor onde está o caractere procurado. e depois só passar ele dentro da `string` até o final.

```
novoValor = id[id.rfind('.')+1:]
```

utilize essa variável `novoValor` e passar no teu `update`.

```
c.execute(f'UPDATE IMPRESSAO SET BINARY = ?,  DATA_ENVIO_BINARY = ? ,NovoVaor = ? WHERE NUM_IMPRESSAO LIKE ?;', (file_name, date, novoValor, id))
```

Para referencia:

[split](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)

[rfind](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_rfind.asp)

Comment: O valor de `novoValor` seria `[3]`, pois você definiu ele igual uma lista com o tamanho da lista subtraído em 1. Acredito que você queria buscar o último valor da lista, então deveria ser `novoValor[len(novoValor)-1]`, mas melhor que isso, basta você passar o índice negativo para buscar o último valor, `novoValor[-1]`, não precisa calcular o tamanho da mesma.

Comment: Inclusive você pode fazer `novo_valor = id[id.rfind('.')+1:]` para obter a última parte após o ponto, isso evitaria a criação de uma lista com todas as substrings apenas para buscar a última, tendo uma economia de memória na execução do código. Lembrando que `id` não é um bom nome para uma variável, visto que estaria sobrescrevendo uma função nativa do Python.

Comment: Isso ai Anderson, existe diversa formas de retornar este ultimo elemento que ela que, só mostrei uma forma. O ideia seria essa ultima forma que tu mostrou `novo_valor = id[id.rfind('.')+1:]`, evitando assim alocação de memória desnecessária.

Comment: O ideal seria corrigir essa forma que apresentou, como comentei no primeiro comentário xD

Comment: Pronto meu velho, valeu a ajuda xD @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: `novoValor = [-1]` isso não deveria ser `novoValor = novoValor[-1]`?

Comment: Isso mesmo @AndersonCarlosWoss, vacilo dos grandes. Valeu. Corrigido!